# List component to bring up InputText boxes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, list, multiplayer, textinput

I'm creating a list component with different numbers on each label ranging from 1 to 10. When clicked on a number I need it to bring up that many inputtext boxes one after another..

It's pretty much a multiplayer game that you select how many players are playing, then you input each name.. I'm so stuck it's ridiculous.. if anyone has a solution, or a different idea please help me out, thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to accomplish this.

**Flash Professional approach**

Author your view on the art board of Flash Professional.

Include a list control, as well as text boxes you want to display, such as:

[image: artboard]

Give property names to your components, such as `quantityList` for the list as well as answer text input controls, such as `answer1` inside an `answerBoxes` custom symbol.

[image: linkage]

In code, you could control the visibility of your answer view by adding this to the timeline:

```
import flash.events.Event;

quantityList.addItem({label:"1", data:1});
quantityList.addItem({label:"2", data:2});
quantityList.addItem({label:"3", data:3});
quantityList.addItem({label:"4", data:4});
quantityList.addItem({label:"5", data:5});
quantityList.addItem({label:"6", data:6});
quantityList.addItem({label:"7", data:7});
quantityList.addItem({label:"8", data:8});
quantityList.addItem({label:"9", data:9});
quantityList.addItem({label:"10", data:10});

quantityList.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

function changeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var numberOfQuestions = event.target.selectedItem.data as int;

    answerBoxes.answer1.visible = (numberOfQuestions > 0 ? true : false);
    answerBoxes.answer2.visible = (numberOfQuestions > 1 ? true : false);
    answerBoxes.answer3.visible = (numberOfQuestions > 2 ? true : false);
    answerBoxes.answer4.visible = (numberOfQuestions > 3 ? true : false);
    answerBoxes.answer5.visible = (numberOfQuestions > 4 ? true : false);
    answerBoxes.answer6.visible = (numberOfQuestions > 5 ? true : false);
    answerBoxes.answer7.visible = (numberOfQuestions > 6 ? true : false);
    answerBoxes.answer8.visible = (numberOfQuestions > 7 ? true : false);
    answerBoxes.answer9.visible = (numberOfQuestions > 8 ? true : false);
    answerBoxes.answer10.visible = (numberOfQuestions > 9 ? true : false);
}
```

When you run, you can select items from the list:

[image: running]

[Working SWF Example](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/quantity-list/quantity-list.swf)

[Flash Pro CS5.5 FLA source code](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/quantity-list/quantity-list.fla)

**Flex - A programmatic approach**

> [image: number-game]

Store quantity values in the list data provider, and on change iterate adding elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;

            import spark.components.TextInput;
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            protected function quantityList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                textInputGroup.removeAllElements();

                for (var i:uint = 0; i < quantityList.selectedItem; i++)
                {
                    textInputGroup.addElement(new TextInput());
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List id="quantityList"
            change="quantityList_changeHandler(event)"
            dataProvider="{new ArrayList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])}" />

    <s:VGroup id="textInputGroup" />


</s:Application>
```

**Flex - A declarative appraoch**

> [image: number-game]

Using Flex state system, you could declaratively layout your view then include components in the desired states.  You could also incorporate transitions between states for animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;

            import spark.components.TextInput;
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            protected function quantityList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                currentState = "quantity" + quantityList.selectedItem.toString();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="quantity1" />
        <s:State name="quantity2" />
        <s:State name="quantity3" />
        <s:State name="quantity4" />
        <s:State name="quantity5" />
        <s:State name="quantity6" />
        <s:State name="quantity7" />
        <s:State name="quantity8" />
        <s:State name="quantity9" />
        <s:State name="quantity10" />
    </s:states>

    <s:List id="quantityList"
            change="quantityList_changeHandler(event)"
            dataProvider="{new ArrayList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])}" />

    <s:VGroup id="textInputGroup">
        <s:TextInput includeIn="quantity1,quantity2,quantity3,quantity4,quantity5,quantity6,quantity7,quantity8,quantity9,quantity10" />
        <s:TextInput includeIn="quantity2,quantity3,quantity4,quantity5,quantity6,quantity7,quantity8,quantity9,quantity10" />
        <s:TextInput includeIn="quantity3,quantity4,quantity5,quantity6,quantity7,quantity8,quantity9,quantity10" />
        <s:TextInput includeIn="quantity4,quantity5,quantity6,quantity7,quantity8,quantity9,quantity10" />
        <s:TextInput includeIn="quantity5,quantity6,quantity7,quantity8,quantity9,quantity10" />
        <s:TextInput includeIn="quantity6,quantity7,quantity8,quantity9,quantity10" />
        <s:TextInput includeIn="quantity7,quantity8,quantity9,quantity10" />
        <s:TextInput includeIn="quantity8,quantity9,quantity10" />
        <s:TextInput includeIn="quantity9,quantity10" />
        <s:TextInput includeIn="quantity10" />
    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Man, I'm so new to this, I have no idea how to use that stuff in actionscript..Hell me even saying that probably sounds pretty ignorant because im sure it's not AS.. Thank you for your help so far though..

Comment: Oh, you wanted a Flash Pro [list control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa6.html) example.  Sorry, basically the same as the programmatic approach listening for `Event.CHANGE` from your list.  I'll try to add that example soon.

Comment: Dude thank you so much, I'll figure out how to get my reputation on this site up so i can upvote your answers.. thanks so much man..

Comment: Updated, including a [link to the FLA source code](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/quantity-list/quantity-list.fla).

Comment: Thank you for helping me man. I just have one more question and I'll leave you alone. There is an android app called "A drinking Game" by PFPDEV. There is a multiplayer prompt that asks how many players, then brings up that many textinput boxes for them to enter their names. What I'm trying to do is essentially that.. When after submitting their names I want a text box at the top to display each name one frame after another. Is there anyway you may have time to help me out? Also, do you have a paypal? I'd like to compensate you when I put the app up knowing my friends will at least buy it.

Comment: Just isolate questions here at Stack Overflow and the community will help.

Comment: Okay, well thank you for all your help Jason, you've been awesome man.